# How to focus TextInput with unknown length of items in an array in React Native? There may be more or less items in the array coming from the database

Tags: react-native, focus, textinput

Basically I have done the focusing the TextInput while the items may be added in the cart or coming from the database. I am using useRef hooks, but when I delete some item or add I have got some error stating more render and less render when I delete or add some items in the cart.

This is cartItems array of having five items.

```json
[
    {
        "isAddedToCart": true,
        "product_id": "1",
        "product_name": "PIN 36MM X 18IN",
        "quantity": 0,
        "unit": undefined
    },
    {
        "isAddedToCart": true,
        "product_id": "2",
        "product_name": "APIN 42MM X 24IN",
        "quantity": 0,
        "unit": undefined
    }, {
        "isAddedToCart": true,
        "product_id": "3",
        "product_name": "PIN 24MM X 10IN",
        "quantity": 0,
        "unit": undefined
    }, {
        "isAddedToCart": true,
        "product_id": "4",
        "product_name": "RAKAB 18MM X 24IN",
        "quantity": 0,
        "unit": "2"
    }
]
```

This is helper function I created.

```js
    export const inputRef = (cartItems) => {
    const inputRefs = []
    cartItems.map((item, index) => {
        if(index != (cartItems.length-1)){
            inputRefs[index] = useRef(null);
        }        
    })

    return inputRefs;
    }
```

This is my TextInput

```js
    <TextInput
    placeholder="Qty"
    placeholderTextColor="#676767"
    style={InputStyleWithoutBorder}
    onChangeText={(quantity) => inputQuantity(item.product_id, quantity, defaultUnit.default)}
    keyboardType={"numeric"}
    value={item.quantity}
    returnKeyType={inputRefs.length == index ? "done" : "next"}
    blurOnSubmit={inputRefs.length == index ? true : false}
    ref={index == 0 ? null : inputRefs[index-1]}
    onSubmitEditing={() => { 
            index == 0 || cartItems.length != index+1 ? inputRefs[index].current.focus() :null
            inputQuantity(item.product_id, item.quantity)
        }    
    }
    />
```

This is working fine until I add or remove some items from the cart.
Focusing is working fine.

[This is the item which can be deleted or can add later from the list of items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjklT.jpg)

[This is the error when I delete items in the cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7qpE.jpg)

[This is the error when I add items in the cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woTYB.jpg)

Comment: Could you paste the code where you define your hooks?

Comment: This is AddOrderScreen.js link
https://ctxt.io/2/AACgu95HFA

Comment: This is Helper.js link
https://ctxt.io/2/AACgh5Z9Fg

Comment: Also please mention if it is not the good way then how to focus dynamic textinput with increasing or decreasing numnber of TextInput. I am waiting for the solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const inputRef = (cartItems) => {
    const inputRefs = []
    cartItems.map((item, index) => {
        if(index != (cartItems.length-1)){
            inputRefs[index] = createRef(null);
        }        
    })
    return inputRefs;
}

This solution is working fine.
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this solution:

```
export const inputRef = (cartItems) => {
  const inputRefs = useRef([])
  inputRefs.current = cartItems.map((item, index) => {
     return inputRefs.current[i] ?? createRef(null);
  })

  return inputRefs;
}
```

Comment: I edit above solution to this

export const inputRef = (cartItems) => {
    const inputRefs = useRef([])
    inputRefs.current = cartItems.map((item, index) => {
       return inputRefs.current[index] ?? createRef(null);
    })
    return inputRefs;
}

and it is showing 
 Cannot read property 'current' of undefined,
also next key is not working now.

Comment: This is working fine 



export const inputRef = (cartItems) => {
    const inputRefs = []
    cartItems.map((item, index) => {
        if(index != (cartItems.length-1)){
            inputRefs[index] = createRef(null);
        }        
    })

    return inputRefs;
}

Comment: I just use createRef in the old solution and it's working fine, could please explain how it's wokring, I am trying to understand the solution.

Comment: createRef will always create a new ref, useRef will create a ref only once and after each further call return the previously created ref.